# Error: Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. no solution i found

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have tried all the stack overflow solutions, however, no luck.
Could any one tell what is the issue in html DOM.

Error:

> Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children`
> nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, FormText, FormLabel, FormCheck } from "react-bootstrap";
const EditProduct = () => {
    debugger;
    let {id} = useParams();

    return (<><FormControl>
        <FormGroup className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <FormLabel>Email address</FormLabel>
            <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            <FormText className="text-muted">
                We'll never share your email with anyone else.
            </FormText>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
            <FormCheck type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
        </FormGroup>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
        </Button>
    </FormControl></>)
}
export default EditProduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your form elements with react-bootstrap's `Form` component instead of `FormControl` component.

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-morning-eqnvi?file=/src/EditProduct.js) to see the working example.

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormText,
  FormLabel,
  FormCheck
} from "react-bootstrap";
const EditProduct = () => {
  return (
    <Form>
      <FormGroup className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <FormLabel>Email address</FormLabel>
        <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
        <FormText className="text-muted">
          We'll never share your email with anyone else.
        </FormText>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
        <FormCheck type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
      </FormGroup>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default EditProduct;
```